# How to perform edge detection of a bitmap using MFC?

Tags: c++

How do I perform edge detection of a bitmap using MFC? I have searched, but I found processes that contained matrices which I could not understand.

Comment: Perhaps you could post what part you're not understanding and we could help you with that?

Comment: i cant ask questions on stackoverflow :( why why? this is so unfair

Answer (score 1):

sobel operator .....the simplest differentiator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Comment: i have learned from a site. see is it correct? 
find the difference for calculating gradient 
A(x,y)=A(x+1,y)-(x-1,y) 
then
A(x,y)=((A(x,y)-Amin)/(Amax-Amin))*255
where Amin and Amax is the min and max value in the image.

Comment: i code this but doest not get the required result.
i  code A(x,y) as COLORREF rgb = dc.GetPixel(x, y); BYTE A = rgb;

Comment: @Sweety Khan: `COLORREF` contains three parts, one for each color component. You can't just convert that to a single byte. Try `BYTE A = BYTE(int(GetRValue(rgb)) + int(GetGValue(rgb)) + int(GetBValue(rgb)) / 3)` . This is effectively a very simple greyscale conversion. As a result, you might not find a red-blue edge.

Comment: i tried to code n i m so near to it. it displays a black background and  edges with red color but its not so prominent, i m so near to it, please see n help.

Comment: COLORREF rgb = dc.GetPixel(x, y);A =(r+g+b)/3;min = A < min ? A: min;max = A > max ? A: max;

Comment: COLORREF rgb = dc.GetPixel(x, y);A =(r+g+b)/3;COLORREF rgb1 = dc.GetPixel(x,y+1);A1 =(r1+g1+b1)/3;COLORREF rgb2 = dc.GetPixel(x,y-1);A2 =(r+g+b2)/3;A = A1-A2;A=((A-min)/(max-min))*255; dc.SetPixel(x,y, A);

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you see the implementation present in openCV  

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#index-205

you can download the openCV libraries for free and can see the code inside the header files.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Link to an actual cv library, then read up on the [canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)

Comment: i have learned from a site. see is it correct? 
find the difference for calculating gradient 
A(x,y)=A(x+1,y)-(x-1,y) 
then
A(x,y)=((A(x,y)-Amin)/(Amax-Amin))*255
where Amin and Amax is the min and max value in the image.

Comment: i code this but doest not get the required result.
i  code A(x,y) as COLORREF rgb = dc.GetPixel(x, y); BYTE A = rgb;